# Ankhsvn package load failure

Tags: visual-studio-2008, version-control, ankhsvn

I have tried using Ankhsvn with VS 2008, and I am getting a Package Load Failure.
Any body got any ideas, how to find out what is causing the problem.
Is there a log file that I can analyse?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with the newest official release (2.1.7115), Visual Studio 2008 and Windows XP. I tried the even newer daily build, but it didn't work either.

The previous release (2.1.6941) works for me - first uninstalled the new version and then installed the previous version from http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/files/documents/175/2226/AnkhSvn-2.1.6941.125.msi

P.S. The "devenv /resetskippkgs" command only restores loading the disabled packages (if you clicked "yes" to the error dialog which asked if you want to disable loading this package in the future).

Comment: It was as simple as that. I have another problem now, but that is another story.

Thanks

Comment: The daily build that was published about an hour ago should fix this problem. A security issue has been fixed in this build, so running the old version isn't adviseable

Comment: I am afraid I got the same error message with the latest daily build

Comment: AnkhSVN 2.1.7115 requires a specific security update from Microsoft to be installed. (SharpSvn started requiring a later VC 2005 CRT after that update was installed on the buildserver). 2.1.7141 and newer contain the right CRT in the setup. (2.1.7115 was removed from our site)

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what version you have installed. There have been a few daily builds last week that had some dependency problems.

You can try running

```
devenv /resetskippkgs
```

If that fails contact the support forum/mailinglist at [the AnkhSVN website](http://ankhsvn.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Just downloaded and tried version 2.1.7115.172 it did not work on VS 2008 + Vista 64
Did as suggested by Riikka Heikniemi (uninstall 2.1.7115.172 and install 2.1.6941.125) and it worked like a charm.
Thx

Comment: AnkhSVN 2.1.7115 requires a specific security update from Microsoft to be installed. (SharpSvn started requiring a later VC 2005 CRT after that update was installed on the buildserver). 2.1.7141 and newer contain the right CRT in the setup.

Comment: Daren: All currently supported AnkhSVN versions (4 years after the question) require the VS 2008 CRT which is not as strict as the 2005 version. (Any version should work; last version recommended). Looking at the old binaries should give you an exact version of the DLL you need. Most likely http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=766a6af7-ec73-40ff-b072-9112bab119c2 is the required one.